# Jasmine testing custom filter that uses angular-translate in AngularJs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-filter, angular-translate

I created a filter using Angular that translates a list from German to English. This is the code for the filter and it works just fine:

```
    .filter('translateItem', ["$translate", function ($translate) {
    return function (item) {
        if ($translate.use() == "en_US"){
            return item;
        }
        if (item=="Montag") return "Monday";
        else if (item=="Dienstag") return "Tuesday";
        else return item;
   };
   }])
```

I am trying to write a unit test for the filter using Jasmine, but it appears that I am not injecting the filter correctly. I get the following error:

> Unknown provider: translateItemFilterProvider <- translateItemFilter

This is the code for the test

```
describe('translateItemFilter', function () {

var translateItemFilter;

beforeEach(module('app.view'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_translateItemFilter_){

    translateItemFilter = _translateItemFilter_;

}));

it('should translate items', function () {

   var item = 'Montag', result;

   result = translateItemFilter(item);

   expect(result).toEqual('Monday');

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you combine the two `beforeEach` lines, it should work:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  module('app.view');

  inject(function (_translateItemFilter_) {
    translateItemFilter = _translateItemFilter_;
  });
});
```